# return value from subshell and output to local variables

Tags: bash, exit-code, bash-function

I've found the strange behaviour for me, which I can't explain. 
The following code is work OK:

```
function prepare-archive {
blah-blah-blah...
_SPEC_FILE=$(check-spec-file "$_GIT_DIR/packaging/")
exit $?
blah-blah-blah...
}
```

means I get value which I expect:

```
bash -x ./this-script.sh:
++ exit 1
+ _SPEC_FILE='/home/likern/Print/Oleg/print-service/packaging/print-service.spec
/home/likern/Print/Oleg/print-service/packaging/print-service2.spec'
+ exit 1
```

As soon as I add `local` definition to variable:

```
local _SPEC_FILE=$(check-spec-file "$_GIT_DIR/packaging/")
```

I get following:

```
bash -x ./this-script.sh:
++ exit 1
+ local '_SPEC_FILE=/home/likern/Print/Oleg/print-service/packaging/print-service.spec
/home/likern/Print/Oleg/print-service/packaging/print-service2.spec'
+ exit 0
$:~/MyScripts$ echo $?
0
```

**Question:** Why? What has happened? Can I catch output from subshell to `local` variable and check subshell's return value reliably?

**P.S.**: `prepare-archive` is called in the main shell script. The first `exit` is the `exit` from `check-spec-file` function, the second from `prepare-archive` function - this function itself is executed from main shell script. I return value from `check-spec-file` by `exit 1`, then pass this value to `exit $?`. Thus I expect they should be the same.

Comment: In what context is `prepare-archive` called? The `++ exit 1` doesn't fit with any code you've shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the bash manual, `Shell Builtin Commands` section:

```
local:
    [...]The return status is zero unless local is used outside a function, an invalid name is supplied, or name is a readonly variable.
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Does this mean that variable definition doesn't have return status when is used without `local`? Why? Do you know some workarounds - as I don't want produce superfluous global variables.

Comment: I'm not aware of any workarounds that don't involve the creation of a global variable or the use of files, sorry =(. I would do `local TMPFILE=$(mktemp); check-spec-file > $TMPFILE; local error=$?; local _SPEC_FILE=$(cat $TMPFILE); rm $TMPFILE`

Comment: @Mephi_stofel - to work around it, you can split the declaration and initialization, e.g. first this: `local my_var` and than that: `my_var=$(my_function)`. the initialization will safely refer to the local variable, without polluting the global scope.

Comment: Thank you, @EliranMalka! I had the same problem today and this is exactly how I solved it.

Comment: Amazing to find this question after you debug for one hour and only then you know how to search on Google/SO. ;)

Answer (score 24):

To capture subshell's exit status, declare the variable as local before the assignment, for example, the following script

```sh
#!/bin/sh

local_test()
{
    local local_var
    local_var=$(echo "hello from subshell"; exit 1)
    echo "subshell exited with $?"
    echo "local_var=$local_var"
}

echo "before invocation local_var=$local_var in global scope"
local_test
echo "after invocation local_var=$local_var in global scope"
```

produces the following output

```
before invocation local_var= in global scope
subshell exited with 1
local_var=hello from subshell
after invocation local_var= in global scope
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what's happening here? Your answer fixed my problem, but I still don't understand how and why it does so.

Comment: @IhorKaharlichenko If a variable is assigned on declaration with `local`, sub-shell exit status is "masked"/overriden by the exit status of the `local` built-in command. Declaring a local variable before assignment is also more portable (some shells don't support initialization with `local`).

Comment: more info: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155

Answer (score 0):

As I use bash subshell parenthesis to group many echo commands I hit this strange problem.
In my case all I needed was to pass one value back to the calling shell so I just used the exit command

```
RET=0
echo RET: $RET
(echo hello
echo there
RET=123
echo RET: $RET
exit $RET)
RET=$?
echo RET: $RET
```

gives the following output

```
RET: 0
hello
there
RET: 123
RET: 123
```

without the exit command you will get this which is confusing:

```
RET: 0
hello
there
RET: 123
RET: 0
```